# RXJS observers slow down each other

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have the page with the documents list on the left (with clickable items, each items will select a document), and the actual content of the selected document in the right side, which takes up the bigger part of the page. The problem is that when a big document is clicked, it causes the delay to display it, but more importantly, the selected menu item (from `EvahubSidenavComponent`) is not displayed immediately, but it seems to be waiting the document content (in `EvahubDocumentsComponent`)  to be displayed first. Why? The document itself, can be as much as 10MBs of text, so it's ok if it needs to be read-in over a second or two, but the menu item on the left (in the evahub-sidenav) should be coloured immediately. I have these two crucial observes in the state store as so:

```
currentDocumentId$: Observable<number> = this.select(
    state => state.currentUser.currentDocumentId
);

// for simplification, I set so the clicked document is always going from 0 to 3, so switcher is serving that purpose as index

switcher = 0;

selectedDocument$: Observable<EvahubDocument> = this.currentDocumentId$.pipe(
    combineLatestWith(this.currentPageIndex$, this.userLogs$),
    map(([docId, cpi, ls]) => {
        return ls[this.switcher++ % 3];
    })
);
```

App component observes the currently selected document's id, so in app.component.ts I have this:

```
currentDocumentId$ = this.store.currentDocumentId$;
```

In the template (`app.component.html`) I have a child component (`EvahubSidenavComponent`) that the `currentDocumentId$` is propagated to simply as input, so like this:

```
<div *ngIf="{
    currentDocumentId: currentDocumentId$ | async,
    ...
    } as asyncData"
>
    <evahub-sidenav
        ...
        [selectedDocumentId]="asyncData.currentDocumentId"
        ...
    ></evahub-sidenav>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Router will in turn contain the 2nd component (`EvahubDocumentsComponent`), which uses `selectedDocument$` from the store like this in its template `EvahubDocumentsComponent.html`

```
<div
    *ngIf="{
        selectedDocument: selectedDocument$ | async,
        currentPageIndex: currentPageIndex$ | async
    } as asyncData"
>
{{ asyncData.selectedDocument.getDocumentContent() }}
```

and takes it like this, in the component itself:

```
selectedDocument$ = this.store.selectedDocument$;
```

To recap, the derived observable `selectedDocument$` is somehow stopping its factor observable, `currentDocumentId$`, until the derived observable finishes and returns. This is not good, I want them to be processed separately and independently. I tried this for the derived observable, with same outcome, i.e. the currentDocumentId$ is delayed:

```
selectedDocument$: Observable<any> = this.currentDocumentId$.pipe(
        mergeMap(cdi =>
            this.currentPageIndex$.pipe(
                combineLatestWith(this.userLogs$),
                map(uls => {
                    return uls[1].find(l => l.logId == cdi);
                })
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Can you pls post the working code on StackBlitz?

Comment: Doesn't your `ngIf` already return true?

Comment: @possum it is a pattern. Yes it will always return true. The *ngIf={.....} part is there to call the observable in the template. Please ignore this part. This part is correct, it is not problematic.....

Comment: @DzmitryAlifer it's dificult because the documents are taken from the DB with python as the API part. It's a bit complicated. I will put more information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting information via python as a (from JavaScript's perspective) synchronous operation.

My second guess is that, because `selectedDocument$` isn't using the `share()` operator, *each* observer is incrementing `this.switcher` and that is (or might soon be) messing things up.

Both can be resolved by changing trying

```js
selectedDocument$: Observable<EvahubDocument> = this.currentDocumentId$.pipe(
    combineLatestWith(this.currentPageIndex$, this.userLogs$),
    map(([docId, cpi, ls]) => {
        return ls[this.switcher++ % 3];
    }),
    shareReplay(1),
    observeOn(asyncScheduler)
);
```

`shareReplay` ensures that late observers start off with the most-recent value that was emitted. Also, without it, the observable and the operators execute per observer.

`observeOn` emits the value on an asynchronous scheduler.

Comment: the switcher is not an issue. Works the same with or without that testing bit. I will however try the shareReplay bit.

Comment: This worked! Please tell me why shareReplay(1) goes on the derived observable, instead on the inner observable? Makes more sense for it to go on the inner observable. Logic: inner observable fires, allows one more replay, so the derived is permitted to take it. Not the other way around. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad! About explaining... when you say "allows one more replay" I think you're misunderstanding. A `share()` operator makes an observable "hot" as long as there's at least one observer, with no restarting or duplication of effort until there are no observers and then it's observed again. `shareReplay(1)` Is the same thing, except when a new observer subscribes, they automatically get the previously emitted value, so `share()` is to `shareReplay(1)` as `Subject` is to `BehaviorSubject`. `shareReplay(100)` means new observers start off with the last *hundred* emissions.

Comment: Oh! I understand your question now, and I think you're right!  The shareReplay and observeOn would be better put on `currentDocumentId$`